# Why is やりたい放題 used as opposed to やり放題?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

A common word in Japanese, meaning "all-you-can-drink", is "飲み放題". It is "放題" - as much as you would like - appended to the verb-stem of "飲む". It is the same rule for instance, for: 食べ放題, 読み放題, （電話）かけ放題 etc...

Why is it then "やりたい放題" as opposed to "やり放題"?

---

- [A Google search for "やりたい放題"](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E6%94%BE%E9%A1%8C%22) returns 1 790 000 results.
- [The same for "やり放題"](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A%E6%94%BE%E9%A1%8C%22) returns 500 000 results, with the top results being from manicure salons.

Comment: You seem to have run into a somewhat common issue. [Google results estimates cannot be taken too seriously](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/522).  When paging through the results of your searches, I get 26 pages and 17 pages, leaving both expressions rather rare and neither being particularly preferred.

Comment: In http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon, やりたい放題 has 74 hits and やり放題 has 12 hits.

Comment: @jkerian You only get 26 pages because results are omitted, though, right? There are still about 1.5 million hits.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't know how many hits there are.  Google only provides *estimates*, and they've never really tried to make the estimates particularly accurate.  We can't conclude from the result estimates alone that either expression is common or rare.  (I think this is a good question, though.)

Comment: From the Google Japanese Web N-gram corpus: `やりたい放題` 306350, `やり放題` 53050

Answer (score 9, accepted):

やりたい放題 is a bit different from other ○○放題. It's an idiomatic phrase which primarily refers to someone's tyrant-like, irresponsible, self-indulgent *behavior*. Because it usually has a negative connotation, it's less likely to serve as a marketing phrase (except [something like this](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00JUL1FJU/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_vaKCwb0THCZX9)).

> 母親が亡くなって以降、あの王女はやりたい放題だ。

やり放題 is less common and may refer to the same thing as やりたい放題. But actually やり放題 is the word that sounds closer to "all-you-can-X" as in 飲み放題, 食べ放題, マンガ読み放題, etc. That's why you got many results from manicure salons (ネイルが○○円でやり放題) and sex-related articles. Unless properly modified (eg レトロゲームやり放題, インターネットやり放題), I personally feel やり放題 can be easily associated with sexual contexts. Please use it wisely.

Comment: I always thought やりたい放題 was a positive expression (essentially equal to やり放題 without the sexual connotation) that _sometimes_ was used to describe the bad behavior and connotation you described. Do you have any reference for that? It's interesting to see the unchecked misinterpretation of nuance I can have.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Judging from the results of [BCCWJ Corpus](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/), it can safely be said that やりたい放題 is mostly negative, and only sometimes neutral.